# Friction and electromagnetic force

Tags: electromagnetism, friction, material-science

What is the relationship between friction and electromagnetic force? At microscopic level, how does electromagnetic force cause friction?

Answer (score 0):

There is no underlying relationship between friction forces and electromagnetic forces.

Friction is the force resisting the relative motion of solid surfaces, fluid layers, and material elements sliding against each other. There are a number of different types of friction forces.

Friction is not itself a fundamental force whereas, the electromagnetic force is a fundamental force. Friction resists motion due to other applied forces, including electromagnetic forces to the extent that electromagnetic forces can cause the motion of things.

Hope this helps.